# replacing open $fh, '|-', ... with pipe

Tags: perl

My code currently looks something like this:

```perl
my $fh;
if (...) {
    open $fh, '|-', 'cmd1', 'arg1', ...;
} elsif (...) {
    open $fh, '|-', 'cmd2', 'arg1', ...;
} elsif (...) {
    open $fh, '|-', 'cmd3', 'arg1', ...;
}
while (...) {
    # do stuff
    print $fh $stuff;
}
close $fh;
if ($!) {
    # error handling
}
```

So depending on some conditions, I execute a different command to which I then write the same content. I now want to conditionally replace one of the commands by a pipeline, so I tried doing this (without error handling for brevity):

```perl
my $fh;
if (...) {
    open $fh, '|-', 'cmd1', 'arg1', ...;
} elsif (...) {
    open $fh, '|-', 'cmd2', 'arg1', ...;
} elsif (...) {
    my $reader, $writer;
    pipe $reader, $writer;
    my $pid = fork();
    if ($pid == 0) {
        open(STDIN, '<&', $fh);
        open(STDOUT, '>&', $writer);
        close($reader);
        exec 'filtercmd';
    }
    close $writer
    open $reader, '|-', 'cmd3', 'arg1', ...;
}
while (...) {
    # do stuff
    print $fh $stuff;
}
close $fh;
if ($!) {
    # error handling
}
```

The intention is to spawn a background process to which I hand `$fd` as standard input which then uses a pipe to write to another process. But of course this doesn't work because at that point `$fh` is not defined. This is no problem when using `open $fh, '|-'` but it is a problem here. Do I have to do something with `$fh` before i can use it as stdin for my forked process which I later want to write to?

**EDIT**

Comments suggested to use `IPC::Open2` instead of rolling it myself with `fork()`. I'm trying to change a project which so far did not use the `IPC` module so I'd like to avoid adding this dependency in my patch but for the sake of the argument, lets try to create a minimal example using `IPC::Open2`. The following is supposed to do something similar to `echo foo | tee /dev/stderr | tee /dev/stderr`. I'm using `tee` instead of `cat` so that we can see `foo` getting printed at each step of the pipeline:

```
my ($reader, $writer, $fh);
pipe $reader, $writer or die "pipe failed: $!";
open2($reader, $fh, 'tee', '/dev/stderr') or die "cannot open2: $!";
open($writer, '|-', 'tee', '/dev/stderr') // die "wpen failed: $!";
print $fh "foo";
```

This will print `foo` only once, so it reaches the first process but then does not get passed on further down the pipeline. Why?

Comment: *"But of course this doesn't work because at that point $fh is not defined."* [IPC::Open3](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Open3) shows an example where [`gensym`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Symbol) is used to create the filehandle beforehand

Comment: *"exec 'filtercmd'"* : Can you give an example of how `filtercmd` is supposed to work?

Comment: Use `IPC::Run` or `IPC::Open2` instead of trying to set it up yourself.

Comment: What does "using [a variable whose value is `undef`] as stdin" mean?

Comment: @HåkonHægland I tried using `gensym` for my `$fh` variable but that just yields `Bad filehandle: GEN0`.

Comment: @HåkonHægland imagine `filtercmd` like something similar to `grep` which takes input on stdin, filters it and writes it to stdout. To test this, using `cat` or `tee` suffices.

Comment: @Shawn the project is not using the IPC module right now so I want to avoid adding a dependency in my patch to it. But for the sake of trying it, I added an example which does not work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @ikegami at the point where i try using `$fh` as a filehandle for STDIN, it is undefined. That's why @HåkonHægland suggested using `gensym` on it. Without that, perl complains "Can't use an undefined value as filehandle reference".

Comment: `open($writer, ...)` Pretty sure that replaces the file handle created by `pipe` with a new one.

Comment: @josch Thanks for the update. Can you provide a complete minimal example with expected input and output from the perl script, `filtercmd`, and `cmd3` ? I think this will help clarify your question.

Comment: "_I'd like to avoid adding this dependency_"  -- Not all libraries are made the same.  The `IPC::Run` is practically a mini-shell.  It's a kind of a full shop for handling external programs. Normally it's used without any other dependencies.  Given what code you show here I'd expect you to have _zero_ trouble picking it up.  At the same time, I find its use for basic jobs _very_ simple (via one command), but there are simpler ones out there, like `IPC::Run3` (`IPC::Open2/3` are a bit low level). I'd easily recommend to adopt `IPC::Run` for managing external programs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *easy* way to do this is just overcome your distaste for modules and use [`IPC::Run`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run). Modules written by smart people allowing you to simply do things that are fairly complex and/or tedious to implement are great; they should be embraced, not shunned. We're not talking Node levels of gratuitous dependencies on `is-odd` here.

A skeleton framework using it:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use IPC::Run qw/start pump finish/;
use Symbol;

my $h; # The IPC::Run harness returned by start
my $fh = gensym; # IPC::Run can open pipes automatically but needs a valid glob reference first
if (...) {
    # Simple case; a single command that reads anything written to $fh
    $h = start ['cmd1', 'arg1', ...], '<pipe', $fh;
} elsif (...) {
    $h = start ['cmd2', 'arg1', ...], '<pipe', $fh;
} elsif (...) {
    # Complex case; a pipeline of multiple commands
    $h = start ['filtercmd'], '<pipe', $fh, '|', ['cmd3', 'arg1', ...];
}
close $reader;
while (...) {
    # do stuff
    print $fh $stuff;
    pump $h; # Might not be needed when not using strings as input/output sources but let's be safe
}
close $fh;
finish $h;
```

and a `echo foo | tee /dev/stderr | tee /dev/stderr` equivalent:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use IPC::Run qw/start finish/;
use Symbol;

# Prints foo three times, twice to standard error, once to standard output

my @tee = qw{tee /dev/stderr};
my $fh = gensym;
my $h = start \@tee, '<pipe', $fh, '|', \@tee;
print $fh "foo\n";
close $fh;
finish $h;
```